# Logo transition to menu can't accept absolute positioning (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm scrolling the logo from the first section of the website should stay fixed and lose its size until it reaches the menu. Then it should stick to the left side of the menu. Everything works great except for the fact that it doesn't fit. I tried making modifications to the JS script so that it adds a class that adds `position: absolute;` but that ruins my navbar.

Live website: http://theworkshop.ro/astra3/

Here's the JS:

```
<!-- Logo transition to menu JS-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var navbar = $('#nav_bar'),
    navbarOffset = navbar.offset().top,
    image = $('#image'),
    imageOffset = navbar.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > navbarOffset) {
        navbar.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        navbar.removeClass('fixed');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > imageOffset) {
        image.removeClass('fixed');
    } else {
        image.addClass('fixed');
    }
});
</script>
```

Similar example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/FyEGN/636/

I'd also like to add some space before the logo in the first section (350px) and I have struggle with that part as well (it keeps the padding in the menu as well). Any help in this area is appreciated however the main question is:

How to fit the logo in the menu that I provided a link for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I used position absolute.
If you want to add more space to the left, just change the left:0 to left:10px;

I also took the liberty to change the original to 
imageOffset = navbar.offset().top -100;
So, the changes will happen before the image reaches the menu. 100 is the height of the image.

Here is the working example:http://jsfiddle.net/FyEGN/639/

CSS:

```
.image {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    margin:25px auto;
    left:0; //this places the image to the left
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
.img-fix{
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
     left:50%;
     margin-left:-100px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var navbar = $('#navbar'),
navbarOffset = navbar.offset().top,
image = $('.image'),
imageOffset = navbar.offset().top -100;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > navbarOffset) {
        navbar.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        navbar.removeClass('fixed');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > imageOffset) {
        image.removeClass('img-fix');
    } else {
        image.addClass('img-fix');
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to get past that, however I need to place the logo on the left part of the menu and it just floats to the center and then sticks there (without resizing).